# Why does std::extent applied to auto& yield zero?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was experimenting with `constexpr auto` and string literals to get character arrays I could use with `std::begin` in a generic way, when I ran into something I couldn't explain: the expression `std::extent<decltype(foo)>::value`, where `foo` is declared using auto reference, yields zero.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <type_traits>

 namespace {
   auto& ARRAY_REFERENCE = "foo";

   template<typename T, std::size_t N>
   std::size_t numberOfElementsIn(T (&)[N]) { return N; }
 }

 int main() {
   std::cerr <<
     "std::extent applied to ARRAY_REFERENCE: " << std::extent<decltype(ARRAY_REFERENCE)>::value << "\n"
     "Number of elements in ARRAY_REFERENCE: " << numberOfElementsIn(ARRAY_REFERENCE) << "\n"
     ;
   return 0;
 }
```

The code above gives me the output

```
std::extent applied to ARRAY_REFERENCE: 0
Number of elements in ARRAY_REFERENCE: 4
```

Why doesn't the expression involving `std::extent` evaluate to 4?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry (not sorry) for the RTFM, but from [`std::extent` at cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent):

> If `T` is an array type, provides the member constant `value` equal to the number of elements along the `N`th dimension of the array, if `N` is in `[0, std::rank<T>::value)`. **For any other type**, or if `T` is array of unknown bound along its first dimension and `N` is 0, **`value` is 0**.

Your `T` is not an array type; it is a reference type.

You can fix this with [`std::remove_reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference):

```
std::extent<std::remove_reference<decltype(ARRAY_REFERENCE)>::type>::value
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18fb0605ced3c132))

Ain't C++ great?

Comment: @Maikel: Yes, awesomely terrible.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I read the [meta.unary.prop.query] section of the standard previously when fooling around with my arrays, but apparently I RTFM rather sloppily when I rechecked it for answers.